# set auto increment value missing in table options

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to set the auto increment value to some value.

I user phpMyAdmin to manage database.

but in the operations tab under the sub heading table options that field is missing.

Table structure is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primary Key: Unique user ID.',
  `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Unique user name.',
  `pass` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'User’s password (hashed).',
  `mail` varchar(254) DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'User’s e-mail address.',
  `theme` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'User’s default theme.',
  `signature` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'User’s signature.',
  `signature_format` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The filter_format.format of the signature.',
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Timestamp for when user was created.',
  `access` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Timestamp for previous time user accessed the site.',
  `login` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Timestamp for user’s last login.',
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Whether the user is active(1) or blocked(0).',
  `timezone` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'User’s time zone.',
  `language` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'User’s default language.',
  `picture` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Foreign key: file_managed.fid of user’s picture.',
  `init` varchar(254) DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'E-mail address used for initial account creation.',
  `data` longblob COMMENT 'A serialized array of name value pairs that are related to the user. Any form values posted during user edit are stored and are loaded into the $user object during user_load(). Use of this field is discouraged and it will likely disappear in a future...',
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `access` (`access`),
  KEY `created` (`created`),
  KEY `mail` (`mail`),
  KEY `picture` (`picture`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Stores user data.';
```

But for other databases in the same server i can see this options.

Can somebody tell why it is missing?

Comment: You should just change to: `uid int(10) unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primary Key: Unique user ID.',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is way to add auto_increment through *operations* but if you go to the *structure* of a table, select *change* on the column you wish to change, there is a checkbox named a_i that indicates auto_increment. Check that and press *save* and your column will have auto_increment.

Comment: Lost a few hours on this: If you add a PRIMARY index on a column, it won't register as auto_increment, you have to also check the A.I. checkbox!